# Struts2 JSON Writer Exception on sending JSON Response

Tags: java, json, struts2, action, gson

I have encountered lots of exceptions that I do not find to be helpful to solve my proble,

here are them

```
Class org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter can not access a member of class org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.javassist.BytecodeProviderImpl$EntityInstrumentationMetadataImpl with modifiers "public"
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter can not access a member of class org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.javassist.BytecodeProviderImpl$EntityInstrumentationMetadataImpl with modifiers "public"
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter can not access a member of class org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.javassist.BytecodeProviderImpl$EntityInstrumentationMetadataImpl with modifiers "public"
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter can not access a member of class org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.javassist.BytecodeProviderImpl$EntityInstrumentationMetadataImpl with modifiers "public"
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter can not access a member of class org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.javassist.BytecodeProviderImpl$EntityInstrumentationMetadataImpl with modifiers "public"
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter can not access a member of class org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.javassist.BytecodeProviderImpl$EntityInstrumentationMetadataImpl with modifiers "public"
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter can not access a member of class org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.javassist.BytecodeProviderImpl$EntityInstrumentationMetadataImpl with modifiers "public"
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter can not access a member of class org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.javassist.BytecodeProviderImpl$EntityInstrumentationMetadataImpl with modifiers "public"
```

Here is my action class that returns the JSON

```
public class GetTagsAction extends ActionSupport{       
    public String execute(){

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String tags = gson.toJson(audioTaggingService.findTagsByName(q));
        System.out.println(tags);

        return Action.SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getQ() {
        return q;
    }

    public void setQ(String q) {
        this.q = q;
    }

    public AudioTaggingService getAudioTaggingService() {
        return audioTaggingService;
    }

    public void setAudioTaggingService(AudioTaggingService audioTaggingService) {
        this.audioTaggingService = audioTaggingService;
    }

    public String getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(String tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    private String q;
    private AudioTaggingService audioTaggingService;
    private String tags;
}
```

Here's the Package

```
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="json-default">
    <!--  Get AJAX Related Actions -->
    <action name="tags" class="tags">
        <result type="json" />
    </action>
</package>
```

And I am using `Struts2-JSON-plugin`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The errors are due the fact that the plugin is trying to convert the entire object graph and it looks like the plugin is trying to convert your database layer via the audioTaggingService. You need to specify the "root" parameter in your struts XML

```
<action name="tags" class="tags">
    <result type="json">
      <param name="root">tags</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

and provide a getTags() method in your action.

However, I'm not sure that this is going to help. I'm not sure what will happen when you try to JSON-ify a String that already contains JSON data.

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit following line in your xml

```
 <action name="tags" class="tags">
```

attribute `class` is looking for a detailed Class name like `com.your.package.YourAction`

detailed [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html)

Answer (score 0):

Some times this error is coming if the one of the JSON data is null, it will not give error while conversion but at the time of processing the data it is giving error.